# detect duplicate array, then push insert to new array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

What if there is an associative array whose value id_post is duplicate, it is inserted into a new array.
the point is like this is image. from $score to $newArray.

```
$score = [
    ['id_post' => '1', 'score' => '4'],
    ['id_post' => '5', 'score' => '10'],
    ['id_post' => '1', 'score' => '7']
];

$newArray = [
    [
        ['id_post' => '1', 'score' => '4'],
        ['id_post' => '1', 'score' => '7']
    ],
    [
        ['id_post' => '5', 'score' => '10']
    ]
];
```

Comment: The question is not making much sense to me. Can you explain what is the current state and what state are you trying to get to?

Comment: i want to set $score into new array like $newArray

Comment: Do you mean you want to *group* them by id_post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Collection class to help you group these:

```
collect($score)->groupBy('id_post')->values()->toArray();
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `values`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray)